Is the existence of physical substances, such as organisms, compatible with physicalism?
I have come across an objection to substance metaphysics on the basis that it is incompatible with physicalism, exemplified in the context of organisms causing their parts to move. The objection is as follows:
Consider an organism (Z) composed of elementary particles (X & Y, only two parts for simplicity). It is commonly taken that causal closure is fundamental to physicalism, all physical events must have physical causes. If I, an organism, cause my arm to move, we could say the organism (Z) causes its arm to move. But for this to happen, the organism would need to impart energy and momentum onto its parts (X & Y).
However, where does this energy come from? It can't have come from X & Y, this would mean that Z, as a substance, doesn't have causal potency. Therefore the organism is causally inert or else the moving of the limb is due to a non-physical cause and breaks causal closure.
My thoughts: First, it seems that the presented formulation of causal closure is not quite true given the indeterministic nature of quantum mechanics. More importantly, I don't know that saying "the organism causes its arm to move" necessarily implies that the organism must directly impart energy and momentum onto its parts. I'm not sure what that would even mean, as they are not on the same "level" in the compositional hierarchy.
What is anyone else's thoughts?

The organism does have causal potency, as do the particles that make it up, and the causal potency of the organism is nothing more than the causal potency of the particles that make it up. When we say "the organism," this can be viewed as a shorthand for, "the particles in a certain pattern of arrangement with each other."
When we say "the organism caused its arm to move," this means nothing more than that particles were initially arranged within the organism in a certain pattern, and a causal consequence of that pattern was that the organism's arm moved.
We could alternatively choose to interpret "the organism" as a term representing nothing, and say that arrangements of particles do not have any existence, only particles do. But if we commit to this interpretation, we would find ourselves completely unable to describe anything happening in the world; language would be useless. We could not say we sit in a chair; no, we would have to sit in an arrangement of particles. We could not say we hit the ball with the bat; no, an arrangement of particles hit an arrangement of particles with an arrangement of particles.
A definition should be evaluated primarily based on its usefulness in communicating ideas. Given a choice between a definition of "the organism" that makes the term useful, and one that makes the term useless, we should choose the definition that makes the term useful. What we call "the organism" is a matter of how we decide to use language, not a matter of fact about the organism.

You say:

If I, an organism, cause my arm to move, we could say the organism (Z) causes its arm to move. But for this to happen, the organism would need to impart energy and momentum onto its parts (X & Y).

So, your question presumes a contradiction when you model an organism to have one set of physical properties as distinct from the physical properties of its parts. This is fallacious thinking. You can say Z imparts energy and momentum to X and Y, but Z is composed of X and Y, and so you're modeling the system as if Z were distinct from X and Y. It is not. Mereology (SEP) is the study of the relations between parts of a system and the whole system. From the article:

Mereology (from the Greek μερος, ‘part’) is the theory of parthood relations: of the relations of part to whole and the relations of part to part within a whole.

Two important informal fallacies related to mereology are the fallacy of composition and the fallacy of division where mistakes are made when assuming what is true of the parts may not be true of the whole and the vice versa. In this case, the conversation of energy applies to the whole system. So, strictly speaking a system and its parts are a closed system, and to treat the organism as a distinct system from its parts creates a contradiction, and a misapplication of causal closure.

But isn't Z ontologically distinct from its parts? Like, if the organism dies, X and Y would still exist, but Z wouldn't.

Yes, but ontological distinctions are psychological, not physical, and therefore the ontological distinctions must defer to the physical. The inference of causality must follow the empirical data.

but you would still affirm the existence of Z in the ontology room, right?
